# How to efficiently unravel arguments to a database in Python

Tags: python, database, function, arguments, variadic-functions

I have the following function which takes 4 arguments (we don't know which are set and which aren't before runtime).

```
myFuct(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    # db insert function for only those args that are set
```

Is there an **efficient way** of unraveling the **set** arguments in a mysql database with a single sql query?

P.S. I am looking for a pythonic way to do this without having to say *if-this-then-that* for a million times...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update with an example of what the input looks like, is it a dicitonary, a list, a long string? What does the table look like? what keys/columns does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you need.

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Can take any number of arguments, is this what you're looking for?

`print(*(1,2,3,4))` * "unravels" the arguments in the order they are given but can be passed as one object or any number of objects.

However, passing these into a SQL statement without knowing the precise length of the arguments. Since SQL to my knowledge is a bit strict on how you pass the arguments.

You could do something like:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    statement = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(" + ', '.join(str(x) for x in args) + ");"
    db.execute(statement)
```

Note of course that this can only be used if you actually pass arguments to myfunc that are of the correct type, order and length.

in postgresql you have something called a prepared statement which would come in handy here.

```
def myfunc(*args):
    statement = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(" + ', '.join('$'+str(i) for i in range(0, len(args)+1)) + ");"
    handle = db.prepare(statement)
    handle(args)
```

Where you simply define `$1`, `$2` and so on in the prepared statement and then pass the equivilant number of arguments to the handler which will execute the query with the correct format on each of the values enabling you to pass integers, strings and arrays.. any way you like :)

Also, if the argument is a dictionary (mentioned in a comment)...
You'd have to do:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    keys = ', '.join(str(x) for x in list(args.keys()))
    values = ', '.join(str(val) for k, val in list(args.items()))
    statement = "INSERT INTO table (" + keys + ") VALUES(" + values + ");"
    db.execute(statement)
```

Again, assumes the dictionary is passed with proper variables for a execution to proceed.

Comment: Let me clarify things: what I need to do is this: If arg1 contains a value, execute an sql statement and update a table with a value taken from arg1. If however both arg1 and arg2 are set then run an sql statement and update a given table in two column with values arg1 and arg2. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable-length argument list construct:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    args_non_empty = [a for a in args if a]
```

This allows you to pass any number of argument to your method. You can easily then filter them by traversing the list.

Comment: How would I know which of them are set so I can make a single sql insert?

Comment: That's already covered, check `args_non_empty`. Try to run this: `myfunc(1, 2, 3, '', None, 'a', 'b', None)` and check `args_non_empty`.

Comment: @pajton i think he's asking, "how do i convert this list of non empty arguments into a INSERT string?" :)

Comment: @Torxed in that case we'd need more info about the desired statement itself :-). And kwargs sound better in this case

Comment: @Torxed Yes, but it's a bit more complicated than that. I actually get a dictionary object from web.py whose values I have to pass to the database. However I don't know which of it's keys are set... In order to do an 'UPDATE' I have to know the nature of the value so that I can update the appropriate column...

Comment: @Konos5 Wow, your question is really vague.. Non of this is mentioned in your post. We'll score so many - points answering your question because we're so way off the solution because we don't have enough information :P

Comment: I will provide the upvote and accept any answer that even helps me a tiny bit towards my actual problem..